# jMeter > Use beanshell to call a test fragment

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Can I call a jMeter test fragment or any other sampler from a beanshell sampler?

I search on https://jmeter.apache.org/api/ but I did not find any method that can be used to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to call a sampler from Beanshell sampler. I am not sure why you would want to do that. Because JMeter call the Samplers one by one - So you can not change the order unless you have some Logic Controllers.

```
The full list of BeanShell variables that is set up is as follows:

log - the Logger
Label - the Sampler label
FileName - the file name, if any
Parameters - text from the Parameters field
bsh.args - the parameters, split as described above
SampleResult - pointer to the current SampleResult
ResponseCode = 200
ResponseMessage = "OK"
IsSuccess = true
ctx - JMeterContext
vars - JMeterVariables - e.g. vars.get("VAR1"); vars.put("VAR2","value"); vars.remove("VAR3"); vars.putObject("OBJ1",new Object());
props - JMeterProperties (class java.util.Properties)- e.g. props.get("START.HMS"); props.put("PROP1","1234");
```